# help! Scheme (programme which find sum and product)

Tags: scheme, sum, product

```
(define sp
  (lambda (l) 
    (if (null? l)
        '(0 1)
        (let ((v (sp (cdr l))))
          (list (+ (car l) (car v)) (* (car l) (car v)))))))
```

What is wrong in my function?

Comment: What do you think is wrong with it?

Comment: it doesn't works.it works when we change (car v) to (cadr v) in product.

Comment: You've answered your own question, then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The return value from your `sp` function is a two-element list. The first element `(car v)` is the partial sum; the second element `(cadr v)` is the partial product. You are using the partial sum in both the sum and product calculation.